# Increase Snippet Size on Google Search Appliance

Tags: search, google-search-appliance

I am currently working on customizing a corporate GSA box for the client's website with Goggle's XSL stylesheet.

Unfortunately I do not have direct access to the box, this involves a meeting with a fellow in another timezone, so experiments and learning is very short on my part.

One of the biggest issues we are having is weather or not it is possible to get more characters/words into a resulting *search-snippet* in the XML output. More specifically, the returned  field.

I've gone through a lot of the documentation for this and so far I've only found the *tlen* value for Title length, but not snippet length.

I know there are some parameters (hidden fields) to customize some options in the search form, but not finding anything relating to this. Since I can not access the Administrator Control panel itself, I've no idea what options are there. Can anyone point me to something that will help with this? It's greatly appreciated, I'm striking out on this.

BTW; we are at the current Version 6.14 I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GSA administrator can increase the length of the snippet.  This is a system wide setting and not able to be customized at query time.

See [this](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/614/help_gsa/serve_query_expansion#snippets)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/admin_console_help/serve_query_expansion.html#snippets

Changing the Snippet Length in Search Results

By default the Search Appliance, for most languages, will return Snippets with the length of 160 characters. Some exceptions to this rule are CJK languages for which Snippets are by default 240 characters. To Change the Snippet Length:

Under Snippet Generation, type a number in the Snippet Length box. The number must be bigger or equal to 0 and not bigger than 1024.
Click Apply Snippets Generation Settings.